# Performance of Minecraft Server on rPi 400

Tags: server, performance, minecraft

I want to create a Minecraft server at home, and have two spare machines that are candidates for this:

- A power hungry Xeon WS-2140B
- A power-sipping rPi 400

I like the low power-usage of the rPi, but how much sacrifice can I expect on performance of running the (java) server?

My ISP is 75Mb/s down, 7.5Mb/s up, in case that matters.

Comment: what is preventing you from running some tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a test yourself. However, from experience, I think the limiting factor is RAM and storage speed. On a Pi 3B (1 GB RAM), the server could not keep up at all and there was significant delay.
It also depends on how many players you are expecting.

Using an SSD over USB 3.0, together with 8 GB RAM will be enough for a vanilla MC server. If your micro SD card is good enough and you have sufficient RAM, you might get away without using the SSD.